# XML External Entities: The Sequel

Tags: xml

There are two threads that deal with my question:

- [xml document having external references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780482/xml-document-having-external-references)
- [How to use external entities in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783578/how-to-use-external-entities-in-xml)

In short, I'm working with external entities for the first time and having a problem.  I was so happy to find the answers in the above thread BUT what I've found is that the answers are not working for me.

In each thread's case, I created the XML files involved on my local computer.  I made sure they were in the same directory and I previewed the file(s) in IE (IE 9 to be exact).  In each case, I ended up with the same problem the user in the second thread reported regarding Chrome and FF but now, for me, it's IE not showing the contents of the external file; it just shows the markup of the original file.  For example, here is what IE shows as the results of thread 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root>
-<root> <tmp id="1"/> <tmp id="2">This is a test</tmp> </root>
```

Any ideas why this might be?  Has IE 9 changed in it's XML parsing?

Thanks in advance,
Kate

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [that thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/845090c6-9d91-410d-99c2-94b201ff893c) seem to indicate that IE9 doesn't load external entities by default.

I can't verify with IE9 myself. IE8 does load the external entity, though.